# Login success/fail with Sweetalert

Tags: sweetalert

How to bring sweetalert when the username and password does not match with the database? Please give me an example with a standar login form. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will show you how to display a sweetalert. You just have to do this with your form.

```html
<head>
    <script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="showcase sweet">
     <h4>Sweet Alert</h4>
     <button>Show error message</button>
        
     <h5>Code:</h5>
     <pre>
            <span class="attr">sweetAlert</span>(<span class="str">"Oops..."</span>,
            <span class="str">"Something went wrong!"</span>,
            <span class="str">"error"</span>);
        </pre>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
  document.querySelector('.showcase.sweet button').onclick = function(){
 swal("Oops...", "Something went wrong!", "error");
  };
</script>
```